# Shell Script to extract the tag value

Tags: text-processing, xml

Suppose I have one xml file as mentioned below and I want to extract the application name, machine and status tag value using unix commands and present it in comma separated format.

**XML file:-**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<applications>
<application name="Adapter/Code1">
<service name="Code1.par">
<deploymentStatus>Success</deploymentStatus>
<serviceInstance name="Code1-One">
    <machine>123</machine>
    <status>Running</status>
</serviceInstance>
<serviceInstance name="Code1-Two">
    <machine>456</machine>
    <status>Running</status>
</serviceInstance>
</service>
</application>
<application name="Adapter/Code2">
<service name="Code2.par">
<deploymentStatus>Success</deploymentStatus>
<serviceInstance name="Code2-One">
    <machine>123</machine>
    <status>Running</status>
</serviceInstance>
<serviceInstance name="Code2-Two">
    <machine>456</machine>
    <status>Running</status>
</serviceInstance>
</service>
</application>
</applications>
```

Output:-

```
Adapter/Code1,123,Running

Adapter/Code1,456,Running

Adapter/Code2,123,Running

Adapter/Code2,456,Running
```

Can you please help me in giving unixcommand/shell script for doing this activity.?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Do what every question tagged xml here suggests: use an XML parser.

Answer (score 2):

***Python*** 3.x solution (with *xml.etree.ElementTree* module):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for app in root.findall('application'):
    for m,s in zip(app.iter('machine'), app.iter('status')):
        print("%s,%s,%s" % (app.get('name'), m.text, s.text))
```

The output:

```
Adapter/Code1,123,Running
Adapter/Code1,456,Running
Adapter/Code2,123,Running
Adapter/Code2,456,Running
```

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=etree#module-xml.etree.ElementTree

---

***xmlstarlet*** + ***awk*** (used to group child nodes for each `application` element) solution:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//application/@name| .//machine/text()| .//status/text()" -n input.xml 
 | awk '/Adapter/{app=$0; r=app; c=0; next}
   { if(++c==2){ c=0; print r","$0; r=app } else { r=r","$0 }}'
```

The output:

```
Adapter/Code1,123,Running
Adapter/Code1,456,Running
Adapter/Code2,123,Running
Adapter/Code2,456,Running
```

---

- `"//application/@name| .//machine/text()| .//status/text()"` - XPath expression to get the needed nodes
- `/Adapter/{app=$0; r=app; c=0; next}` - capturing each `application` name for further concatenation

http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html

Comment: cool ! ( +1 ) ( python version also works in Python2 ?)

Comment: @JJoao, as for Python 2 - it has `print` function call without parenthesis (i.e. `print <arg>`),  but I hope Python 2.x will die someday )

Answer (score 1):

Install **xidel** and use xpath.

In my opinion the best point of view is from `serviceInstance`:

```
xidel f.xml -e '//serviceInstance/string-join((../../@name, machine, status),",")'
```

```
Adapter/Code1,123,Running
Adapter/Code1,456,Running
Adapter/Code2,123,Running
Adapter/Code2,456,Running
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `xmlstarlet` to loop over each `serviceInstance` node:

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t \
    -m '//application/service/serviceInstance' \
    -v '../../@name' -o , \
    -v 'machine' -o , \
    -v 'status' -nl \
    file.xml
```

This matches the `serviceInstance` nodes, and for each such node, it extracts the `name` attribute of its grandparent node, the `machine` node's value and the `status` node's value.  These are outputted with commas in-between them (`-o ,`) and a newline at the end (`-nl`).

You may also get quoted CSV output from `xq` (from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/):

```bsh
xq -r '
    .applications.application[] | ."@name" as $name |
    .service.serviceInstance[]  | [ $name, .machine, .status ] | @csv' file.xml
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have good reason for not using xml tools, you can use low-level parsing, as long as your application stays trivial as your example:

```
sed 's/<application name="\([^"]*\)">/\1/
Ta
h
d
:a
/<machine>/!d
G
N
s_.*<machine>\(.*\)</machine>\n\(.*\)\n.*<status>\(.*\)</status>.*_\2,\1,\3_' yourfile.xml
```